# What does it mean when the beginning of a sentence is 'To Think' (followed by a comma)?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english

For example,
"My name rolled out of his tongue like it laced the abhorrence of a deplorable word. He might consider using to it summon the devil. To think, I hated my last name."

I don't understand the sentence.

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

"To think," in this case, is an exclamation expressing the speaker's surprise at an unexpected realization. In writing, it is mainly used in dialogue or, perhaps even more commonly, in a character's direct internal dialogue.

Comment: I like it, but if you could please add a citation :)

Answer (score 1):

"To think," it's being used as "I can't believe"

I found a thread where someone asked a similar question.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27318/to-think-idiom

Answer (score 0):

Poorly written sentences; translated?
Possible alternate reading:

"*My name rolled off his tongue like some foul oil, having the consciousness of a snake. He might well have use it to summon the devil. **Imagine**, at that moment, I hated my last name*."

"To think," often means "imagine", as in "try to imagine".

Comment: That's not really what it means. "To think that . . ." really means "It is strange/bizarre/astounding to think that . . ."

Comment: @Robusto: We probably have regional variation here.

Answer (score 0):

'To think' is generally meaning amazement along with shock. Oxford learner's dictionary gives this for the entry of the word 'think' as a verb, as 'to think(that...)'.

In this context, a comma has been used and not 'that'. Since comma and 'that' aren't substitutes for one another so the phrase could have a slightly different meaning as shown below

"My name rolled out of his tongue like it laced the abhorrence of a deplorable word. He might consider using to it summon the devil. *Just imagine*, how much I (must have) hated my last name."

Answer (score -1):

### Can you believe it?

To think, by simply replacing the `ì` in `shit` with `o` will make the word `shot`.